# Difference between Observable#single() and Observable#toSingle()?

Tags: java, rx-java, system.reactive, reactive

I stumbled upon these to methods and from what I get from the docs, they do the almost the exact same thing. Looking at the code they clearly do different stuff. From starters `single()` returns an `Observable` (why?) while toSingle() effectively returns a `Single`.

My limited knowledge of the reactive world leaves me wondering, why both these methods exists? What differences do they have? Should any of them use the other?

Do any or both of them `immediately` transform the `Observable` to a `Single` and, if it hasn't emitted any items, it throws an error? Or do they wait for the events to get emitted?

Another thing that baffles me is that their marble diagrams are different
([toSingle](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/ReactiveX/RxJava/images/rx-operators/Single.toSingle.png) and [single](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/ReactiveX/RxJava/images/rx-operators/single.png)), but what their docs say they should behave exactly the same, in particular they should behave like `single()` marble diagram.

Here are the docs:
[Observable#toSingle](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#toSingle)
[Observable#single](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#single--)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation for each operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why both these methods exists?

`single()` is part of the original ReactiveX set of operators. `toSingle()` has been added later when `Single` was introduced into RxJava.

> What differences do they have?

They return a different base reactive class. `single()` stays `Observable` and `toSingle()` converts to `Single`.

> Should any of them use the other?

Depends on what types you want to use and whether or not you plan to move to RxJava 2.x soon. In RxJava 2, there is no `toSingle` and (most) operators now return a more appropriate type: `single(T)`,  `singleOrError()` or `singleElement()`.

> their marble diagrams are different

`toSingle`'s marble doesn't feature the error case and `Single` type's time diagram has slightly different convention to represent event over time than with `Observable`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that both are identical, both will produce 1 item on upstream completion, both will produce error if supplied with more than one item (as the documentation states), so the safe way of using them would be *observable.take(1).toSingle()* or indeed *observable.take(1).single()*